# Calculate focal statistics from a 10m raster to populate a 1km raster, using the 1km raster to define the window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-conversion, aggregation, focal-statistics

I have a binary raster (1-0), cell size = 10m.

I would like to generate a 1km raster, where cell values equal the mean value of all cells within a 3 km radius. I know I can use focal statistics to generate a 1km raster from a 1km raster using a window.

But is there any way to calculate the mean of all the 10m cells that fall within a window around each 1km cell (i.e. window being a circular with radius = 3km)?

Comment: Is Block Statistics what you are after?: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/block-statistics.htm

Comment: Yes, that will work! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, now I had a chance to try it. Block statistics won't work! I need each cell to have its own unique (i.e. moving) window. preferably circular. 

If I use the snap raster and raster analysis environments to snap to another 1km raster, and set the cell size equal to the 1km raster it seems to work. 

Is there any reason I shouldn't do this?

Comment: You can specify a circular neighborhood with block statistics. Setting a snap environment is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

[Block Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/block-statistics.htm) will work well for your workflow.

> Partitions the input into non-overlapping blocks and calculates the
> statistic of the values within each block. The value is assigned to
> all of the cells in each block in the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#EcologicalModelling #RasterAnalysis #Predictors #Topographic #Habitat #Focalstatistics #NeighborhoodAnalysis #worldclimate #copernicus #googleearthengine

https://medium.com/@valentino.pintar/how-to-prepare-predictors-for-ecological-modelling-e442601120e3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).